# Conditional Fields with multiple conditions

Tags: entities

I am using Conditional Fields module. I need some guidance when setting dependencies for multiple fields (accepting unlimited values). Here is the situation:

In my entity form I have two fields:

1. Assignment Status --> This is Select List type with two values DRAFT and FINAL
2. Upload File -->  This field is required field for accepting documents from student ONLY when Assignment status is FINAL else it is optional field.

Now my question is when I am using this case and creating Dependent and Dependee relation only for one assignment this work fine but when I give an option for accepting unlimited values the Conditional Fields doesn't work.

Because one student is required to submit more than one assignment I used Paragraph Module and also tested this case also  with MultipleFields Module. I am not able to find any answer to my query. Please help me to find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the module [Reference Option Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit)

With this module you can try to make a reference.

The documentation of this modules is here

[Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1596310)

Is a Great module, hope i can help you